# How to combine dates and times?

Tags: python, datetime

I want to add a time to a datetime. My initial datetime is: `initial_datetime='2015-11-03 08:05:22'` and is a string and `this_hour` and `this_min` are strings too. I use:

```
time='-7:00'
time = time.split(':')
this_hour = time[0]
this_min = time[1]
initial_datetime='2015-11-03 08:05:22'
new_date = datetime.combine(initial_datetime, time(this_hour, this_min))  
           + timedelta(hours=4)
```

But there comes an error:

> 'str' object is not callable.

My desired output is the `initial_datetime` plus my time (in this case -7 hours ) and then add 4 hours. So, in my example, the new date should be '2015-11-03 05:05:22'.

Comment: sorry its not date.today(), it should be initial_datetime

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: You probably have something like `time = <some string>` before in your code.

Comment: What is `this_hour` and `this_min`?

Comment: My time is time='-7:00' it's a string and i split it with time.split(':') and than use this_hour = time[0] this_min = time[1]

Comment: And my desired output is the initial_date plus my time (in this case -7 hours ) and than add 4 hours. so, in my example the new date should be '2015-11-03 05:05:22'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`datetime.combine` is typically used to combine a `date` object with a `time` object rather than incrementing or decrementing a `datetime` object. In your case, you need to convert your datetime string to a `datetime` object and convert the parts of your time string to integers so you can add them to your datetime with `timedelta`. As an aside, be careful about using variable names, like `time`, that conflict with your imports.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dtstr = '2015-11-03 08:05:22'
tstr = '-7:00'
hours, minutes = [int(t) for t in tstr.split(':')]

dt = datetime.strptime(dtstr, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + timedelta(hours=hours+4, minutes=minutes)
print(dt)
# 2015-11-03 05:05:22
```